# Массив работает только внутри своего метода... как сделать так чтобы он работал и в других методах?

Tags: java

В идеале было бы хорошо каждый метод сделать отдельно... только я не понимаю как сделать что бы это все было взаимосвязано и можно было каждый раз обращаться к этому массиву, создавать "новый" я не хочу?(

```
public class Massiv {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int maxNegIndex = 0;
        int minPosIndex = 0;
        int[] mas = new int[20];

        for (int i = 0; i < mas.length; i++) {

            mas[i] = (int) ((Math.random() * 21) - 10);

            //замена чисел
            if (mas[i] < 0) {
                if (mas[i] > mas[maxNegIndex])
                    maxNegIndex = i;
                if (mas[maxNegIndex] >= 0)
                    maxNegIndex = i;
            } else if (mas[i] > 0) {
                if (mas[i] < mas[minPosIndex])
                    minPosIndex = i;
                if (mas[minPosIndex] <= 0)
                    minPosIndex = i;
            }
            // System.out.print(mas[i] + " ");

        }

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(mas));
        int temp = mas[maxNegIndex];
        mas[maxNegIndex] = mas[minPosIndex];
        mas[minPosIndex] = temp;

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(mas));
    }


    static void sum(int[] mas ) {

        int sum = 0;
        int n = 0;

        System.out.println( "Четные элементы:" );

        for ( int i = 0; i < mas.length; i++ ) {   
            if ( mas[i] % 2 == 0 ) {
                ++n;
                sum += mas[i];
                System.out.print( " " + mas[i] );
            }
        }
        System.out.println( "Всего четных элементов " + n );
        System.out.println( "Их сумма равна " + sum );
    }
}
```

Comment: Поясните, что значит `массив работает внутри метода`? И как именно он `не работает`?

Comment: ну вот методом sum этот массив уже не вызывается... и так далее... там еще другие методы... они тоже его не видят( В методе main где я его создал массив активен... а в других методах уже к нему доступа нет...

Comment: Хотите из 'psvm' передать массив в `sum()` ?

Comment: Нужно передать массив параметром в метод... а я не знаю как

Comment: sum(mas); /////

Comment: static void sum(int[] mas ) - здесь замена на static void sum(mas ) не помогла(( Или что то другое имелось ввиду?

Comment: Внутри метода `main()` вызывайте `sum(mas)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Для начала очень рекомендую вам почитать про KISS, SOLID  (а лучше еще и GRASP). Первая буква S означает принцип единственной ответственности. Это означает в данном конкретном случае, что каждый метод должен иметь единственное предназначение. Ваш метод  sum() выполняет сразу 2 функции - считает количество четных элементов и их сумму (я уже молчу про вывод в консоль). Это будет препятствовать его переиспрользованию в дальнейшем. Принцип KISS говорит "сделай это проще". Посему ваш метод превращается в 2 метогда с четкими обязанностями и максимально простым кодом. Первый метод я не рефакторил, поскольку магии его предназначения мне непонятна, простите)) А ваша проблема решается не разбиением на классы, а, опять таки, корректным разбиением на методы функционала класса (смотрим паттерн GRASP information expert) и отказом от статики.
Выглядит это в итоге так:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Massiv {

    private final int[] mas;

    public Massiv(int size) {
        this.mas = new int[size];
    }

    public int[] generate() {

        int maxNegIndex = 0;        
        int minPosIndex = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < mas.length; i++) {

            mas[i] = (int) ((Math.random() * 21) - 10);

            //замена чисел
            if (mas[i] < 0) {
                if (mas[i] > mas[maxNegIndex]) maxNegIndex = i;
                if (mas[maxNegIndex] >= 0) maxNegIndex = i;
            } else if (mas[i] > 0) {
                if (mas[i] < mas[minPosIndex]) minPosIndex = i;
                if (mas[minPosIndex] <= 0) minPosIndex = i;
            }

        }

        int temp = mas[maxNegIndex];
        mas[maxNegIndex] = mas[minPosIndex];
        mas[minPosIndex] = temp;

        return mas;
    }

    public int sumEvenElements() {        
        return Arrays.stream(mas).filter(i->i % 2 == 0).sum();
    }

    public int[] evenElements() {
        return Arrays.stream(mas).filter(i->i % 2 == 0).toArray();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Massiv massiv = new Massiv(20);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(massiv.generate()));

        int[] evenElements = massiv.evenElements();
        System.out.println("Четные элементы: " + Arrays.toString(evenElements));
        System.out.println("Всего четных элементов: " + evenElements.length);
        System.out.println("Их сумма равна: " + massiv.sumEvenElements());

    }

}
```

Comment: первый метод менял в массиве местами крайние значения)

Comment: @ Никита Кузьмищев это я понял, я не понял зачем, если массив содержит рандомные элементы?))

Comment: после кода в вопросе, код в этом ответе как смазка для глаз

Comment: Я понял как нужно было делать))) Спасибо))

Comment: @MidNightElf да ладно, все когда-то учились)) во мне просто живет надежда на то, что эти ответы читают большое количество людей и поэтому в этом мире станет больше хороших разработчиков и хорошего кода. устал собеседования проводить в поисках нормальных разрабов))

Comment: @Никита Кузьмищев не за что. удачи в изучении)